# Google Maps Store Locator - modify default example

Tags: csv, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a store locator based off the static csv example used by Google http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/panel.html

I have recreated this example on my own server but if I edit the csv file in any way, even if I just remove some of the rows it returns a blank map.

I was hoping I could use this example as a template by replacing the default values in the csv file with my own(http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/medicare.csv). There is clearly more to it than I assumed and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction in terms of why I can't just edit the fields in the csv with my own values and what else should I be editing?

This is their main page http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/index.html

I have been searching online for a way to do this and I have now asked this question here as I am struggling to find an answer.

Comment: please post the modified CSV-file

Comment: Even if I just remove some of the rows from the original csv, the map shows blank. I assumed it would have just showed fewer locations. Here is a link to that csv http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9333930/medicare11.csv

Comment: the parseRow_ method(defined in [medicare-static-ds.js](http://storelocator.googlecode.com/git/examples/medicare-static-ds.js) requires the values to be enclosed by double-quotes, the modified CSV doesn't follow this requirement )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems when I opened in excel it was reformatting the csv file and causing it not to work. When I edit the fields from the csv in notepad++ it works. Apologies for the useless question. Thanks Dr Molle for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: Excel automatically cut off all quotes in the original file